# How to clone git repo from EC2

Tags: django, git, amazon-ec2

[image]

I have set up a django project on EC2 following https://shirtdev.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/setting-up-a-git-repository-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/. Now I want to clone it so that I can develop locally. The instructions in the tut say:

```
git clone username@hostname.com:the_project.git
```

I know this can't be right because I would need to use a private key and the path to the project is:

```
/home/ubuntu/tproxy/testproject
```

How cam I clone this repo?