# 502 Bad Gateway connecting Nginx to django via socket

Tags: python, linux, django, sockets, nginx

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I've gotten everything working down to http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#running-the-django-application-with-uwsgi-and-nginx. I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2:

My django project is called tp. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Following the instructions I have done:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --socket /tmp/mysite.sock --module /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/tp
/wsgi.py --chmod-socket=664
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Thu Mar  5 16:50:02 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 March 2015 02:58:28
os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-28-196
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1fe5320
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ImportError: No module named '/home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/tp/wsgi'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 24393, cores: 1)
```

Obviously you can see:

```
ImportError: No module named '/home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/tp/wsgi'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

How do I set the path to the wsgi.py file?

edit 1: here's my ini file:

```
# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
 [uwsgi]
 # Django-related settings
 # the base directory (full path)
 chdir           = /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp
 # Django's wsgi file
 module          = uwsgi
 # the virtualenv (full path)
 home            = /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1
 wsgi-file       = /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/tp/wsgi.py
 # process-related settings
 # master
 master          = true
 # maximum number of worker processes
 processes       = 3
 # the socket (use the full path to be safe
 socket          = /tmp/mysite.sock
 # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
 chmod-socket    = 664 
 # clear environment on exit
 vacuum          = true
```

I ran:

(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini

but still getting a 502 error.

Logs:

```
2015/03/05 18:10:00 [crit] 1828#0: *51 connect() to unix:///tmp/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 107.0.193.131, server: 52.10.**-**, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/mysite.sock:", host: "52.10.**-**:8000"
```

edit 2 : is home the directory for virtualenv? I set:

```
home            = /home/ubuntu/tproxy/
```

Now:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Thu Mar  5 18:59:27 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 March 2015 02:58:28
os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-28-196
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/tproxy/
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put it in your uwsgi ini file. Here is an example one:

```
 [uwsgi]
 # Django-related settings
 # the base directory (full path)
 chdir           = /var/www/virtualenv/project
 # Django's wsgi file
 module          = uwsgi
 # the virtualenv (full path)
 home            = /var/www/virtualenv/
 wsgi-file       = /var/www/virtualenv/project/projectsettings/wsgi.py
 # process-related settings
 # master
 master          = true
 # maximum number of worker processes
 processes       = 10
 # the socket (use the full path to be safe
 socket          = /tmp/mysite.sock
 # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
 chmod-socket    = 664 
 # clear environment on exit
 vacuum          = true
```

This is my ini file minus my path's to my projects. I also ran into this same issue when installing it myself but was able find the appropriate answer from looking at other configs on google.

Comment: Thanks man, for virtualenv do you need to specify which virtualenv?

Comment: Update virtual env to your path. So the ones you need to update with your paths to each of the directories is: chdir, home and wsgi-file

Comment: almost, change home to `/home/ubuntu/tproxy/`

Comment: Wait, are you project files not inside of your virtualenv folder? I thought tproxy was the name of your virtualenv folder...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72366/discussion-between-electrometro-and-user61629).

Comment: So the problem was needed chmod 777 in uwsgi_ini file

Comment: At this point in time. However, once you start running it in emperor mode in a production environment you need to set it to 664

Comment: BTW , do you ever use git with ec2? I have a question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777891/how-to-clone-git-repo-from-ec2

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with GIT.

Comment: Would you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903269/uwsgi-importerror-no-module-named-site-on-ubuntu?